# Как зарегистрировать yii\web\JqueryAsset?

Tags: yii, yii2

Как зарегистрировать yii\web\JqueryAsset версии min?
И допустим , `jquery.color-2.1.0.min.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример конфига с их [вики](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/785/use-minified-version-of-jqueryasset-bootstrapasset-and-all-default-assets/) (смысл в том, что min/не-min подставляется в зависимости от окружения, можно и просто min вписать):

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
        'bundles' => [
                    'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                        'js' => [
                            YII_ENV_DEV ? 'jquery.js' : 'jquery.min.js'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                        'css' => [
                            YII_ENV_DEV ? 'css/bootstrap.css' : 'css/bootstrap.min.css',
                        ]
                    ],
                    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                        'js' => [
                            YII_ENV_DEV ? 'js/bootstrap.js' : 'js/bootstrap.min.js',
                        ]
                    ]
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: а как без тернарного оператора ? и с новой версией , а то там старая подставляется.

Comment: ну без тернарника будет просто 'js' => ['jquery.min.js'] и т.д., на счет версии - дак какая в этом ассете есть, такая и подставляется, что мин, что не мин. если нужна своя версия - выкидывайте коробочный ассет и подключайте нужные либы руками в своих ассетах...

Comment: Я так и делаю, подключаю через свой ассет. Просто я хотел использовать базовые билбиотеки, такие как JQuery, в единственном экземпляре для всех виджетов. А то у меня ппц получается. Вот например подключил форму, а она экспортирует по умолчанию базовую старую версию JQuery. А мой виджет нужlается в новой версии. И того получается на одну html , страницу приходится 2-е Jquery. Это минус скорость загрузки как минимум...

Comment: я вам даже сразу скажу горя с двумя версиями на странице вы еще хлебнете. как вариант можно попробовать вообще в дефолтном JqueryAsset проставить js => [], если там где-то оно подтягивается без вариантов и подключать везде только 1 свою версию руками. можно даже весь этот yii\web\JqueryAsset => false выставить, по ситуации в общем импровизировать...

Comment: yii\web\JqueryAsset => false -  я так и сделал. Значит иду правильным путём.  Спасибо вам.